# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'

Tags: 16.04, apache2, mysql, php

I have launched my Symfony project in browser but I have this problem in error.log

```
[:error] [pid 4789] [client ::1:39684] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 
'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in /var/www/html/ensoSteps/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/ensoSteps/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php(43): PDO->__construct('sqlite:/var/www...', NULL, NULL, Array)\n#1 /var/www/html/ensoSteps/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOSqlite/Driver.php(60): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->__construct('sqlite:/var/www...', NULL, NULL, Array)\n#2 
/var/www/html/ensoSteps/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(360):Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOSqlite\Driver->connect(Array, NULL, NULL, Array)\n#3 /var/www/html/ensoSteps/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(1365): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->connect()\n#4 
/var/www/html/ensoSteps/vendor/jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal/src/Jackalope/Transport/DoctrineDBAL/Client.php(2619): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->getWrappedConnection()\n#5 
/var/www/html/ensoSteps/vendor/jackalope/jack in 
/var/www/html/ensoSteps/vendor/jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal/src/Jackalope/Transport/DoctrineDBAL/Client.php on line 460
```

Help me please for solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve never used Symfony but it looks like you’re missing the SQLite driver for the PDO (PHP Database Objects) extension.

This is provided by the `php5-sqlite` package which can be installed by running:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite
```

Comment: i make commande of install sqlite but i have this error : Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-sqlite is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5-sqlite' has no installation candidate

Comment: @dev_2017 I just notice from the tags that you're running 16.04 which uses PHP 7. I don't have access to my 16.04 system but I'd guess the relevant package is called `php7-sqlite`.

Comment: i install package php5.6 but i haven't install php5-sqlite and i receiver message bug

Comment: @dev_2017 My last suggestion is to try installing `php5.6-sqlite` or `php5.6-sqlite3`. After that, I'm out of ideas.